# What is the best way to redirect serial data output for example Serial to Serial1

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded

I am doing a project where the interface with the user is depending on their situation using the Arduino IDE and just a standard ATmel328p. (micro)

Some users will interface through Serial terminal. (Serial.print used)
Some users will interface through Serial terminal but with Bluetooth. (Serial1.print used, micro has 2 serial interfaces)
Some users will have an LCD screen. (yet to be implemented)

I am looking for the best way to reroute data from my application, which uses classes, to the right interface without having to rewrite all code.

I thought about using a function pointer and using it as an argument in the conrstuctor of my class objects. So i just change one function and all the data gets funneled out the right way.

```
void wrapperfunction(char* data) {Serial.print(data);}

Class SOMETHING {
SOMETHNG(void (output)(char*)){}
}
```

I am using a char* to transmit the data, so i am sending some strings.
(this gives compilation warnings for casting string to char* but ok, i can live with that i guess?).

works well with strings, but the problem is that my program also uses int- and float values.
So just changing all the Serial.print statements used for earlier prototyping isn't working. I have to cast everything to string or char first.

When i convert all ints and floats to string using the String() function
i also noticed this is quite expensive, all the string functions take about 20% of my memory... :(

This got me wondering if I am on the right track to tackle this problem...
I hope some more experienced coders in embedded C++ can give me some advice to what is best practice for a problem like this.

Thanks in advance,

PS : my first question on SO, i am already sorry if i broke some of the rules ;-)

Comment: Those classes are derived from the base class Stream (and stream is derived from Print), that means you can use something like this:   `Stream & output = cond ? Serial : Serial1;` and then `output.println("whatever");` as it's interface inherited from the Print base class. You can also read data because of Stream base class.

Comment: Simply pass the port along as a parameter to whatever functions you are using.

Comment: I found a solution.
I made a function output(void data, int type) in which i pass the data raw and parse it to the right type afterwards.